# Cycles 2.90 Amdkmdag.sys crash with RX580

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Since a week ago I do have a continuous amount of freezing and BSOD in my computer when i render heavy archviz poly scenes in my gpu+cpu.

The problem seems common with amd's drivers, but maybe someone have faced the same problem and could help me.

Running Windows 10, RX580 8gb, 16gb. Everything stock frequencies.

Thanks!

Comment: If your computer crashes then the issue is not (only) in Blender, but in the graphics driver. You could try to do a clean install or perhaps an older version to see if this solves the issue. For reference the same issue has been posted on the bug tracker in ticket [T80624](https://developer.blender.org/T80624). Please adhere to the submission template the next time you create a ticket, ideally by following [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/74827).

Comment: But running games is fine, even in 100% gpu scenario. Its just Cycles. About the bug tracker it is actually myself posting there too in hope to be helped by someone. I have tried to downgrade drivers version, change to "Enterprise" amd drivers... Nothings changes. I will run the scene from 2.90 to 2.83 and see if it is actually the 2.90 version the problem. Thanks you very much nonetheless and sorry for the non-use of template, il follow it next time.

Comment: It's not a matter of using the GPU, but how the GPU is used. Blender apparently uses something in OpenCL the driver doesn't handle properly. A user space application can't crash the operating system without a bug in the OS or drivers.

Comment: I supposed that, i read something about blender expecting a response from the drivers and the program shutting down itself when the gpu was busy to send back any info. Any solutions in alternative or it is what it is?

Comment: The developers will investigate potential bugs in Blender, since you've opened a ticket (there are also other tickets that report problems with AMD GPUs). However the cause of the BSOD can only be fixed by a patch for the driver.

Comment: Okey, thank you a lot for the quick response and for keeping a nice community as blender have!